# How to keep navigation buttons in a offer slider

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using offer slider in my website which contains 16 slides. I want to keep navigation(previous and next buttons) to the slider where I can able to move to each slide using those buttons.(At present there are navigation buttons which move from one page to another page which I don't want)

Is this possible?

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li>    
        <div class="image" id="s1">
        <img src="images/s10-img.png" width="203" height="226" alt="s10">
        </div>                                      
    </li>
    <li>    
        <div class="image" id="s2">
        <img src="images/s10-img.png" width="203" height="226" alt="s10">
        </div>                                      
    </li>
    <li>    
        <div class="image" id="s3">
        <img src="images/s10-img.png" width="203" height="226" alt="s10">
        </div>                                      
    </li>
    <li>    
        <div class="image" id="s4">
        <img src="images/s10-img.png" width="203" height="226" alt="s10">
        </div>                                      
    </li>
    <li>    
        <div class="image" id="s5">
        <img src="images/s10-img.png" width="203" height="226" alt="s10">
        </div>                                      
    </li>
    <li>    
        <div class="image" id="s6">
        <img src="images/s10-img.png" width="203" height="226" alt="s10">
        </div>                                      
    </li>
.........
16slides    
</ul>
```

**js**

```
if ( typeof( os_args )==='undefined' ) os_args = [];
var os_speed = ( os_args.speed ) ? os_args.speed : 500;
var os_timeout = os_args.timeout;

var os_title = '.title';    // slide title element selector
var os_desc = '.desc';      // slide description element selector

var os_pagerElementsOnPage = 1;     // number of pager elements on page
var os_pagerElementWidth = 160;
var os_pagerWidth = os_pagerElementsOnPage * os_pagerElementWidth;

var os_manual = false;      // true - pause, false - play
var os_currPage = 0;        // current page number ( 0 - start )
var os_slidesCount = 0;     // slides count
var os_pagesCount = 0;      // pages count

function setPagerWidth() {
    var pagerLenght = jQuery('#os_pager > ul > li').length;
    var pagerWidth = pagerLenght * os_pagerElementWidth; 
    jQuery('#os_pager > ul').width(pagerWidth);
}

function goToPage(page) {
    jQuery('#os_pager > ul').animate({
        'left': '-' + os_pagerWidth * page + 'px' 
    },500);
}

function goToNextPage() {
    var os_nextPageFirstSlide = 0;
    var os_nextPage = os_currPage + 1;

    if ( os_nextPage < os_pagesCount) {
        os_nextPageFirstSlide = os_nextPage * os_pagerElementsOnPage;
    } else {
        // tu mozna zrobic blokowanie powrotu do poczatku jesli ma nie byc petli
    }

    os_manual = false; // pokaz ma sie wznawiac po kliknieciu next/prev
    jQuery('#os_cycle').cycle(os_nextPageFirstSlide);
}

function goToPrevPage() {
    var os_prevPageFirstSlide = 0;
    var os_prevPage = os_currPage - 1;

    if ( os_currPage <= os_pagesCount) {
        os_prevPageFirstSlide = os_currPage - 1;
    } else {
        // tu mozna zrobic blokowanie powrotu do poczatku jesli ma nie byc petli
        os_prevPageFirstSlide = ( os_currPage + 1 );
    }

    os_manual = false; // pokaz ma sie wznawiac po kliknieciu next/prev
    jQuery('#os_cycle').cycle(os_prevPageFirstSlide);
}

// creates pager elements
function pagerAnchorBuilder(id, slide) {
    var output = "";
    var title = jQuery('#os_cycle > li:eq('+id+') .title h2').text();
    var thumbnail = jQuery('#os_cycle > li:eq('+id+') .thumbnail img').attr('src');
    output += "<li>"+
        "<a href='#'>"
        +"<div class='icon'>"
        +"<img src='"+ thumbnail +"' />"        
        +"</div>"
        +"<p>"+ title +"</p>"
        +"</a>"
        +"</li>";   

    return output;
}    

function onBefore(curr, next, opts, fwd) {
    jQuery(next).find(os_title).css({'display':'none', 'right':'-950px'});
    jQuery(next).find(os_desc).css({'display':'none', 'left':'-950px'});

    // prevent doing this when pager element click
    if (!os_manual)
    {
        if (opts.nextSlide == 0) {
            os_currPage = 0;    
        }
        else if (opts.nextSlide % os_pagerElementsOnPage == 0) {            
            os_currPage += 1;
        }
        goToPage(os_currPage);
    }
}

function onAfter(curr, next, opts, fwd) {
    jQuery(this).find(os_title).css({'display':'block'}).delay(70).stop().animate({'right':'0px'}, 250, 'easeOutQuad');
    jQuery(this).find(os_desc).css({'display':'block'}).delay(250).stop().animate({'left':'0px'}, 400, 'easeOutQuad');
}

function init() {
    setPagerWidth()
    os_slidesCount =  jQuery('#os_pager > ul > li').length;
    os_pagesCount = os_slidesCount / os_pagerElementsOnPage;
    os_pagesCount = Math.ceil(os_pagesCount);
}

jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $('#Offer_slider .controls').append('<div id="os_pager"><ul></ul></div>');

    $('#os_cycle').cycle({
        fx:         'scrollLeft',
        easing:     'easeOutQuad',
        cleartype:  false,
        speed:      os_speed,
        timeout:    os_timeout,
        nowrap:     0,
        sync:       0,
        pause:      1,  // pause on hover
        randomizeEffects:   0,
        before:     onBefore,
        after:      onAfter,
        pager:      '#os_pager > ul',
        pagerAnchorBuilder: pagerAnchorBuilder 
    });

    init();

    $('#os_pager > ul > li > a').click(function(){
        os_manual = true;
        $('#os_cycle').cycle('pause');
    })

    $('#next_arrow').click(function(){
        goToNextPage();     
        return false;
    });

    $('#prev_arrow').click(function(){
        goToPrevPage();     
        return false;
    });

});
```

Comment: As a general answer... anything is possible. In your case it might actually be quite simple, is just that I don't exactly understand what you want. Can you make a fiddle or something?

Comment: @zoo See I want to have a navigation buttons which allows me to slide forward and backward thats it.

Comment: Ok... from what I get you have buttons that call functions goToNextPage() and gotoPrevPage(). A quick solution (although not exactly the best practice) would be to make the current script to treat each of your slides as a page. From what I see in your script this is already done by setting os_pagerElementsOnPage = 1. This should get you one element per page. I fail to see the problem (if I understood correctly the concepts of page and slide). How exactly is that script failing?

Comment: @zozo yes my problem is forward button is working fine.when the backward button is clicked it iterating only once i.e, when the slider is in 5th slide if i click on backward button it slides to 4th slide if i click the button again it is not sliding to 3rd slide it is sliding to 4th slide. Is there a way to overcome this?

Comment: Ah... well... you should edit your question ;). This is a bit of a long shot since I didn't actually run the script, I just... compiled it in mind, but try editing function goToPrevPage(), and change line os_prevPageFirstSlide = os_currPage - 1; into os_prevPageFirstSlide = os_prevPage - 1;. If this works but breaks other things, undo that, and add this line at the end of the function os_currPage = os_currPage - 1;. If this works I'll post it as an answer (I don't do that directly because as I said... I just analyzed script in mind, didn't implement and test it).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31528/discussion-between-thejdeep-and-zozo)

Comment: Can't right now. I'm at work. In about 30 min.

Comment: I'm on... I'll stay like 10 min or so.

Comment: No problem,I have done the modifications as you mentioned.It is jumping from one slide to other slide. The next button also creating some jump issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OFFFFFFFFFFFFO atlast i found my own solution.... Please check the updated code below for the solution.
Only thing I have changed is previous and next buttons code.

Hope that helps anyone else.

***js***

```
if ( typeof( os_args )==='undefined' ) os_args = [];
var os_speed = ( os_args.speed ) ? os_args.speed : 500;
var os_timeout = os_args.timeout;

var os_title = '.title';    // slide title element selector
var os_desc = '.desc';      // slide description element selector

var os_pagerElementsOnPage = 1;     // number of pager elements on page
var os_pagerElementWidth = 160;
var os_pagerWidth = os_pagerElementsOnPage * os_pagerElementWidth;

var os_manual = false;      // true - pause, false - play
var os_currPage = 0;        // current page number ( 0 - start )
var os_slidesCount = 0;     // slides count
var os_pagesCount = 0;      // pages count

function setPagerWidth() {
    var pagerLenght = jQuery('#os_pager > ul > li').length;
    var pagerWidth = pagerLenght * os_pagerElementWidth; 
    jQuery('#os_pager > ul').width(pagerWidth);
}

function goToPage(page) {
    jQuery('#os_pager > ul').animate({
        'left': '-' + os_pagerWidth * page + 'px' 
    },500);
}

function goToNextPage() {
    var os_nextPageFirstSlide = 0;
    var os_nextPage = os_currPage + 1;

    if ( os_nextPage < os_pagesCount) {
        os_nextPageFirstSlide = os_currPage * os_pagerElementsOnPage;
    } else {
        // tu mozna zrobic blokowanie powrotu do poczatku jesli ma nie byc petli
    }

    os_manual = false; // pokaz ma sie wznawiac po kliknieciu next/prev
    jQuery('#os_cycle').cycle(os_nextPageFirstSlide);
}

function goToPrevPage() {
    var os_prevPageFirstSlide = 0;
    var os_prevPage = os_currPage - 1;

    if ( os_prevPage <= os_pagesCount) {
        os_prevPageFirstSlide = (os_currPage - 1) * os_pagerElementsOnPage;

    } else {
        // tu mozna zrobic blokowanie powrotu do poczatku jesli ma nie byc petli
        os_prevPageFirstSlide = os_prevPage - 1;
    }
    os_currPage = os_currPage - 1;
    os_manual = false; // pokaz ma sie wznawiac po kliknieciu next/prev
    jQuery('#os_cycle').cycle(os_prevPageFirstSlide);

}

// creates pager elements
function pagerAnchorBuilder(id, slide) {
    var output = "";
    var title = jQuery('#os_cycle > li:eq('+id+') .title h2').text();
    var thumbnail = jQuery('#os_cycle > li:eq('+id+') .thumbnail img').attr('src');
    output += "<li>"+
        "<a href='#'>"
        +"<div class='icon'>"
        +"<img src='"+ thumbnail +"' />"        
        +"</div>"
        +"<p>"+ title +"</p>"
        +"</a>"
        +"</li>";   

    return output;
}    

function onBefore(curr, next, opts, fwd) {
    jQuery(next).find(os_title).css({'display':'none', 'right':'-950px'});
    jQuery(next).find(os_desc).css({'display':'none', 'left':'-950px'});

    // prevent doing this when pager element click
    if (!os_manual)
    {
        if (opts.nextSlide == 0) {
            os_currPage = 0;    
        }
        else if (opts.nextSlide % os_pagerElementsOnPage == 0) {            
            os_currPage += 1;
        }
        goToPage(os_currPage);
    }
}

function onAfter(curr, next, opts, fwd) {
    jQuery(this).find(os_title).css({'display':'block'}).delay(70).stop().animate({'right':'0px'}, 250, 'easeOutQuad');
    jQuery(this).find(os_desc).css({'display':'block'}).delay(250).stop().animate({'left':'0px'}, 400, 'easeOutQuad');
}

function init() {
    setPagerWidth()
    os_slidesCount =  jQuery('#os_pager > ul > li').length;
    os_pagesCount = os_slidesCount / os_pagerElementsOnPage;
    os_pagesCount = Math.ceil(os_pagesCount);
}

jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $('#Offer_slider .controls').append('<div id="os_pager"><ul></ul></div>');

    $('#os_cycle').cycle({
        fx:         'scrollLeft',
        easing:     'easeOutQuad',
        cleartype:  false,
        speed:      os_speed,
        timeout:    os_timeout,
        nowrap:     0,
        sync:       0,
        pause:      1,  // pause on hover
        randomizeEffects:   0,
        before:     onBefore,
        after:      onAfter,
        pager:      '#os_pager > ul',
        pagerAnchorBuilder: pagerAnchorBuilder 
    });

    init();

    $('#os_pager > ul > li > a').click(function(){
        os_manual = true;
        $('#os_cycle').cycle('pause');
    })

    $('#next_arrow').click(function(){
        goToNextPage();     
        return false;
    });

    $('#prev_arrow').click(function(){
        goToPrevPage();     
        return false;
    });

});
```